# Hibernate timestamp - millisecond precision

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb, milliseconds

Seems like storing timestamps with millisecond precision is a know issue with hibernate. 
My field in the db was initially set as timestamp(3), but I've tried datetime(3) as well...unfortunately, it didn't make any difference.

I've tried using Timestamp and Date classes, and recently I've started using joda-time library. After all those efforts, I still wasn't unable to save timestamps with millisecond accuracy.

My mapping for the class contains following property:

```
<property name="startTime" column="startTime"    type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime" length="3" precision="3" />
```

and I'v custom defined Dialect class

```
public class MySQLQustomDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect{
    protected void registerColumnType(int code, String name) {
        if (code == Types.TIMESTAMP) {
            super.registerColumnType(code, "TIMESTAMP(3)");
        } else {
            super.registerColumnType(code, name);
        }
    }
}
```

If I enter the data manually into db, hibernate manages to retrieve the sub second part.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: I've never tried what you're attempting... Why not convert into milliseconds since epoch (UTC) and then store that as a long? Most of the times a conversion doesn't really happen since many time keeping objects work with milliseconds since epoch already.

Comment: That would be the best solution, but the database is used by another applications and changing the schema would have a huge impact on these.

I've temporarily solved the issue by executing native sql query to save these. The only problem I see with it is that my code now becomes database dependent.

Answer (score 4):

Are you, by any chance, using the MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver with MariaDB 5.5?

Connector/J usually sends the milliseconds part to the server only when it detects that the server is new enough, and this detection checks that the server version is >= 5.6.4. This obviously does not work correctly for MariaDB 5.5.x.

You can see the relevant part of Connector/J source here:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/connectorj/5.1/view/head:/src/com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.java#L796

Using MariaDB's own JDBC driver (MariaDB Java Client) might help (I haven't tried), but I accidentally discovered that adding useServerPrepStmts=true to the connection string makes this work with Connector/J, too.

Comment: I'm using MySQL JDBC Connector/J, but the server is running MariaDB 10.0.7. And it isn't a problem with Connector/J as executing native SQL query works. Its something to do with hibernate itself.

Comment: Using useServerPrepStmts=true solved it for me.

MySQL Connector/J JDBC 5.1.34

MariaDB 5.5