# How to compare objects with a Date variable (Hibernate)? java.util.Date vs java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, hibernate, date, jakarta-ee, timestamp

Environment:

- MySql 5.6.14
- Spring MVC
- Hibernate

I'm having problems to check if 2 objects are equal, and the problem is caused by de variable Date.

I'm using Hibernate and it seems to be the problem of Timestamp (nanoseconds) and Date(miliseconds).

When I create the object Task date is different that when I retreived the object from database.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date datesql = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
java.util.Date stamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
Date rightnow = stamp;//Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

Task t1 = new Task("My first task", "This is a task", rightnow,
        rightnow, category, priority, state, user, user, "okey", 0);
Task t2 = new Task("My second task", "This is a task", date,
        rightnow, category, priority, state, user, user, "okey", 0);
Task t3 = new Task("My third task", "This is a task", datesql,
        rightnow, category, priority, state, user, user, "okey", 0);
    taskDao.saveOrUpdate(t1);
taskDao.saveOrUpdate(t2);
taskDao.saveOrUpdate(t3);
taskDao.saveOrUpdate(t4);

List<Task> tasks = taskDao.getAllTasks();
assertEquals("Should be 4 tasks.", 4, tasks.size());

Task taskR1 = taskDao.get(t1.getIdTask());
Task taskR2 = taskDao.get(t2.getIdTask());
Task taskR3 = taskDao.get(t3.getIdTask());
//Dates before saving objects in database
System.out.println("l timestamp> "+rightnow.getTime());
System.out.println("l date     > "+date.getTime());
System.out.println("l datesql  > "+datesql.getTime());
//Dates from retrieved objects
System.out.println("l tr1date  > "+taskR1.getDate().getTime());
System.out.println("l tr2date  > "+taskR2.getDate().getTime());
System.out.println("l tr3date  > "+taskR3.getDate().getTime());
```

Results of this code

```
//Dates before saving objects in database
l timestamp> 1401298705937
l date     > 1401298705937
l datesql  > 1401298705937
//Dates from retrieved objects
l tr1date  > 1401298706000
l tr2date  > 1401298706000
l tr3date  > 1401298706000
```

The problem is that when compare 1401298705937 (Date before saving object) and 1401298706000(Date after saving object) are different.

I've also tried with compareTo and equals functions

```
System.out.println("t3.getDate().compareTo(taskR3.getDate()) == 0 :" 
  + (t3.getDate().compareTo(taskR3.getDate()) == 0));
System.out.println("t3.getDate().equal(taskR3.getDate()) == 0 :" 
  + (t3.getDate().compareTo(taskR3.getDate()) == 0));
System.out.println("taskR3.getDate().compareTo(t3.getDate()) == 0 :" 
  + (t3.getDate().compareTo(taskR3.getDate()) == 0));
System.out.println("taskR3.getDate().equal(t3.getDate()) == 0 :" 
  + (t3.getDate().compareTo(taskR3.getDate()) == 0));
```

And result is false, as well with objects t1, t2 and taskR1, taskR2.

```
t3.getDate().compareTo(taskR3.getDate()) == 0 :false
t3.getDate().equal(taskR3.getDate()) == 0 :false
taskR3.getDate().compareTo(t3.getDate()) == 0 :false
taskR3.getDate().equal(t3.getDate()) == 0 :false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could format each date to a string and compare that.

Comment: t3 date  Wed May 28 19:38:25 CEST 2014 and
tR3 date 2014-05-28 19:38:26.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before that Date is inserted into MySQL with Hibernate

```
 1401298705937 = Wed, 28 May 2014 17:38:25 GMT
```

After that Date is recovered from MySQL with Hibernate

```
 1401298706000 = Wed, 28 May 2014 17:38:26 GMT
```

Date value has been rounded from 1401298705937(milis) to 1401298706000(milis) and that is why the objects aren't compareTo()==0

The **solution** I've found, it is to rule out milis before set Date or Timestamp and saving the object with hibernate.

```
new java.util.Date((date.getTime()/1000)*1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

From you example:

1401298705937 = Wed, 28 May 2014 17:38:25 GMT
1401298706000 = Wed, 28 May 2014 17:38:26 GMT

Meaning the DB simply strips millis.

According to [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-basic-value-timestamp):

- java.util.Date
- java.sql.Timestamp
- java.util.Calendar

are all mapped to JDBC TIMESTAMP.

From now on it's the database whose responsible of storing the timestamp and not all versions are able to handle milliseconds.

- PostgreSQL has [microsecond precision.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html)
- MySQL 5.6 has just recently added [fractional seconds support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html), while [previous versions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) stored the timestamps without millis:

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and
>   time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

Is it that you use MySQL 5.5 or lower?

Comment: Actually, I'm using MySql 5.6.14

Comment: Check the actual column types in DB, and try running a manual insert having a timestamp containing millis. If that works, you can try adding the same entry with JDBC and see if it works. This way you can isolate the problem better.

Comment: Also you might be interested in trying the proposed extended dialect of this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142614/hibernate-timestamp-millisecond-precision).

Comment: This must be an Bug in MySQL http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27838, although I'm using MySQL 5.6

Comment: But that's an old issue from 2007, it was not filled for the latest version.

Comment: yes, it is something in between java code and mysql, so it must be Hibernate. I've just tried to insert a date without milis and JUnit test works fine. date = new java.util.Date((new java.util.Date.getTime()/1000)*1000); Not elegant but...

Comment: Check the extended dialect proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142614/hibernate-timestamp-millisecond-precision